# Optional chaining operator in groovy not working as expected?

Tags: groovy

How can I concisely set a default value for a value of a closure that is not populated?

Below I thought using the optional chaining operator would prevent throwing an exception, but I still got an exception.

```
myfunction {
    FOO="myfoo"
    BAZ="mybaz"
}

def myfunction(Closure body = {}) {
    body()

    foo = body?.FOO ?: "defaultFoo"

    // getting exception since BAR isnt defined
    bar = body?.BAR ?: "defaultBar"
    
    println("foo=" + foo + " bar=" + bar)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by setting a dedicated `Binding` on your closure with a map that returns a default value (e.g. `null`) for non-existing keys.

```
myfunction {
    FOO="myfoo"
    BAZ="mybaz"
}

def myfunction(Closure body = {}) {
    def binding = new Binding([:].withDefault {}) // <1>
    body.setBinding(binding) // <2>
    body()

    foo = binding.FOO // <3>
    bar = binding.BAR

    println("foo=" + foo + " bar=" + bar)
}
```

Output:

```
foo=myfoo bar=null
```

There are three critical changes to your code.

1. You define `new Binding([:].withDefault {})` object, where `[:].withDefault {}` is a map that returns a value defined inside the closure for any key that does not exist. In our case, we use an empty closure to return `null` value, but if we do e.g. `[:].withDefault { 1 }`, then we create a map that returns `1` for non-existing keys.
2. Next, you have to call `body.setBinding(binding)` to make use of this custom `Binding` instance.
3. And finally, you read values from the `binding` object, not the `body` closure.